# writing output to file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I need to read input from a text file and create a new text file with the output in it. At the moment my code is reading fine but it is writing only the last line of data, not going through all the lines. Can someone please help me fix this?

```
def generate_daily_totals(input_filename, output_filename):
  """Returns date followed by the sum of values"""
  infile = open(input_filename)

for line in infile:
    content = line.split(",")
    date = content[0]
    total = 0
    for value in content[1:]:
        total = total + float(value)
    rounded_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
    summary = date + " " + "=" + " "  + rounded_total
  outfile = open(output_filename, "w")
  outfile.write(summary)    

generate_daily_totals('data60.txt', 'totals60.txt')
checker = open('totals60.txt')
print(checker.read())
checker.close()
```

The input is

```
2006-04-10,836.2,563.263
2006-04-10,462.06,1694.3,666.0
2006-04-10,1318.19,1485.62
2006-04-10,49.714,304.0,1269.0
2006-04-10,1360.0,1731.0,28.6
2006-04-10,998.879,890.264,367.0
2006-04-10,757.4,1501.05,861.6
2006-04-10,1218.0,270.0
```

What I am getting for output is

```
2006-04-10 = 1488.00
```

But the correct one should be

```
2006-04-10 = 1399.46
2006-04-10 = 2822.36
2006-04-10 = 2803.81
2006-04-10 = 1622.71
2006-04-10 = 3119.60
2006-04-10 = 2256.14
2006-04-10 = 3120.05
2006-04-10 = 1488.00
```

Comment: I think your indentation is wrong. Surely the for loop should be inside the function?

Comment: @Dan yes you're right, it is in the function, i wrote it wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is opening your output file afresh inside the loop. Each time it does that, it overwrites what it did the previous time through the loop.

```
outfile = open(output_filename, "w")
outfile.write(summary)
```

Open your output file before you start looping through the input.

```
with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
  for line in infile:
    content = line.split(",")
    date = content[0]
    total = 0
    for value in content[1:]:
        total = total + float(value)
    rounded_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
    summary = date + " " + "=" + " "  + rounded_total + "\n"
    outfile.write(summary)
```

Comment: Yes this would be more efficient than my answer.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I get it on a new line each time?

Comment: Unlike `print`, the `write` function expects you to manage your own newline characters if you want them, because if you were writing a binary file, you wouldn't want them: `summary = date + " " + "=" + " "  + rounded_total + '\n'`

Comment: @Dan My concern was not efficiency. If you use append, then you also have to supply code to empty the target file beforehand. Otherwise the solution only works as intended the first time.

Comment: @BoarGules thank you for the help, I got it shortly after asking! :)

Comment: @lpe47 If the answer worked for you, please accept it, even if you worked it out yourself independently (and well done for that). I like the points, of course, but the more important reason is that the green tick is helpful to people who find this question via a search engine.

Comment: @BoarGules thanks for telling me, I'm still new to this so had no idea about the green tick, cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the following line:

```
outfile = open(output_filename, "w")
```

By opening the file as a write file, you override everything else in the file. Instead you should use append:

```
outfile = open(output_filename, "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the output file in `append` mode.

```
def generate_daily_totals(input_filename, output_filename):
    """Returns date followed by the sum of values"""
    infile = open(input_filename)

    for line in infile:        
        content = line.split(",")
        date = content[0]
        total = sum(map(float, content[1:])) # No need for the inner loop
        rounded_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
        summary = date + " " + "=" + " "  + rounded_total        
        outfile = open(output_filename, "a")
        outfile.write(summary + '\n')

generate_daily_totals('data60.txt', 'totals60.txt')
```

Output written to the file:

```
2006-04-10 = 1399.46
2006-04-10 = 2822.36
2006-04-10 = 2803.81
2006-04-10 = 1622.71
2006-04-10 = 3119.60
2006-04-10 = 2256.14
2006-04-10 = 3120.05
2006-04-10 = 1488.00
```